# How can I see why Task.Isfaulted is true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, post

I'm following [this](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/) blog. I want to create post method which will accept file.

```
[HttpPost]
        public Task<IEnumerable<FileDescDto>> Post()
        {
            var folderName = "Uploads";
            var PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName);
            var rootUrl = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, String.Empty);
            if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(PATH);
                var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileDescDto>>(t =>
                {

                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                    {
                       throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                    }

                    var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i => {
                        var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                        return new FileDescDto(info.Name, rootUrl + "/" + folderName + "/" + info.Name, info.Length / 1024);
                    });
                    return fileInfo;
                });

                return task;
            }

            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }
    }
```

When I debug, I get that t.IsFaulted is true, and it fails to upload. 
How can I see why it fails and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to await the async method instead of using a continuation? You could just use try/catch then.

Comment: From that blog: _"First, a small disclaimer, all the code here is .NET 4.0 specific – you could easily make it 4.5 by **replacing the `Tasks` with `async` and `ContinueWith` with `await`**."_

Comment: @Fildor: IIRC he wouldn't even need a try catch as every uncaught exception in a WebAPI/MVC method will automatically yield a response with HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError.

Comment: @ckuri That's correct. I personally tend to log details and rethrow in such cases. Especially while in "first" development phase, where I probably step it through.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a `Task` is faulted, `theTask.Exception` will show you exactly what happened, but frankly, it would be a *lot* easier to simply `await theTask` and use regular exception handling. `ContinueWith` is a legacy feature (see the 4.0 disclaimer that Filder pointed out), and should rarely be used in new code. This whole method could be `async` very easily.